# min of row on Matlab GPU with arrayfun

Tags: matlab, gpu

I would like to find the index of the smallest value resulting from some computation, like the nearest value, using Matlab gpuArrays.

However, in the arrayfun scenario the min function doesn't seem to offer the functionality.

With the following code:

```matlab
function grid_gpu_test
    gridSize = 8;
    grid = gpuArray(rand(gridSize));

    all_c=1:gridSize; % because : is not supported

    function X = min_diff(row)
        X = min(abs(grid(row,all_c)-grid(row,1)))
    end

    rows = gpuArray.colon(2, gridSize)';
    arrayfun(@min_diff, rows)
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Too few input arguments supplied to: 'min'. Error in 'grid_gpu_test' (line: 9)
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I know that using `min(gpuArray)` works normally when it's not in arrayfun, but I want to achieve this with an operation that doesn't simplify into matrix operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question, because your code errors out when you try to run it on the CPU. By making `rows` go `2:(gridSize+1)`, then it exceeds the size of `grid`.

In any case, I think here rather than `arrayfun`, you want to use `bsxfun` (or implicit expansion if you have R2016b or later). Here's the `bsxfun` version.

```
grid = gpuArray.rand(8);
% I think what you're trying to compute is the difference
% between each column of "grid" compared to the first column
difference = bsxfun(@minus, grid(:,1), grid);
% To find the minimum difference, and its column, use
% the following form of MIN
[val, col] = min(difference, [], 2)
```

Here I'm using the "reduction" form of `min`, and I want to reduce across columns, so I need to pass in the `2` as the third argument. The second argument is `[]` to tell MATLAB that you want the "reduction" form of `min`, rather than the element-wise form of `min`. (Note that `gpuArray/arrayfun` supports only the element-wise form of `min`, which explains the error you're seeing).

Based on the extra information in the comments, perhaps [`xcorr2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html) is what you're after (this works on the GPU).

Comment: Thank you! The reason I want to use arrayfun is because I want to achieve a more complex operation than the difference between each column with the first column. I want to find the nearest matching 5x5 neighborhood for each element, without storing them explicitly. Does that make sense, or should I reformulate the question code?

Comment: it shouldn't be gridsize+1, my mistake. Fixed it.